# Load data for the ViewModel Items in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to display data from my SQL Server Compact 3.5. On my OnNavigateTo function, I have stated the codes but I am not sure why it is not able to load it. I am using Pivot App, Is it possible to use that to display my data? If yes, what have I done wrong. In the header=today is where I am displaying my data. Thanks.
Below are my codes

MainPage.xaml

```
 <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="DAILY ROUTINE">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="activity">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="today">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>

        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using MyPhoneApp1.Resources;

namespace MyPhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
         * */


        using (ToDoListContext c = new ToDoListContext(ToDoListContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            c.CreateIfNotExists();
            c.LogDebug = true;
            MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoLists.ToList();
        }

    }
    private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var si = MLongListSelector.SelectedItem as MyPhoneApp1.ViewModels.ItemViewModel;

        if (MLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ To Do List"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/todolistPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        else if (si.LineOne.Equals("+ Reminder"))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/reminderPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected item to null (no selection)
        MLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
    }


}

}
```

I have debugged it and below is the SQL Statements

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Title]
FROM [ToDoLists] AS [t0]
```

Comment: does c.ToDoLists contain data? have you checked with breakpoint

Comment: Yes it has 3 datas. What do u mean by checked with breakpoint. How do i do it

Comment: add a breakpoint in your code by clicking in left margin (adds red dot) then run application and code will break so you can check variables ie c.ToDoLists

Comment: You've got a binding already on the list. Why don't you clear the list, and just add the new items, or set the `Items` view model property to the new list?

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie, I am still new here i am sorry. I don't get what you meant by add 'add the new items, or set the Items view model property to the new list'

Comment: I've added an answer that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest you directly set the `ItemsSource` property as you've already established a `Binding` in the XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MLongListSelector" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
```

Since the `Binding` `Path` is set to `Items`, changing the data of the list stored in `Items` will cause the UI to update automatically.

```
// get the list ...
var list = c.ToDoLists.ToList();
Debug.Assert(list != null);
// clear any existing items, which will in turn remove all items from the UI
App.ViewModel.Items.Clear();
// for each item in the list, add it to the existing bound Items list
foreach(var item in list) {
   // you may need to transform the data here
   // The item must be the right type ...
   App.ViewModel.Items.Add(item);
}
```

As it looks like you're using the WP8 template, the `ToDoLists` property needs to return an enumerable list of `ItemViewModel`s or the call to `Add` will fail. You could create new instances of an `ItemViewModel` if the types don't match (for example):

```
var itemViewModel = new ItemViewModel() {
    LineOne = item.Text,
    LineTwo = item.Description
};
App.ViewModel.Items.Add(itemViewModel);
```

The above code assumes then that a todo list item might look like this:

```
public class TodoItem {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: owh! You are right. Because I used the built in templatePivot App. I noticed its different from Databound App. Thank you so much!! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the problem you are binding the MainLongListSelector twice
in Xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
```

and in c#

```
 MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoLists.ToList();
```

Looks like you need to remove the xaml binding

Comment: Hi @dellywhell, I have already removed it in the xaml and remain the xaml.cs but it still didnt work

Comment: Hi, I have updated my questions by adding SQL Statements when I debugged.